# why can't i compile in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, compilation, building

[image]

All that shows up when I press Build is this, could someone explain why this is happening and how to fix it? I can't find this problem mentioned anywhere else.

I have the latest version, I haven't tried anything, because I honestly don't know what I can do to try to fix this. I can't find anyone else with the same problem. I have another project that can compile perfectly fine, and it was made in the exact way I made this one, so I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I have never seen this behavior.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]